# How Can I Make My "Fake ESM" Next 12 Project Use Native ESM?

Tags: next.js, es6-modules

I had a perfectly working Next.js version 11 site, which used Babel/webpack to get modern "ES Module" syntax: the only `require`/CommonJS syntax in my whole app was in `next.config.js` and `babel.config.js`.

I updated it to Next 12 and it worked great, so I figured I'd try to get rid of those remaining requires, and make my project fully ESM, by adding `"type": "module"` to my `package.json`.

That gave me an error about how `next.config.js` had to use ESM syntax, so I updated it to ESM syntax ... but now I get an error about how Next is (evidently?) using Common JS to import the `babel.config.js`?

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:
> /home/me/project/client/babel.config.js require() of ES modules is not
> supported. require() of /home/me/project/client/babel.config.js from
> /home/me/project/client/node_modules/next/dist/build/babel/loader/get-config.js
> is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent
> package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in
> that package scope as ES modules. Instead rename babel.config.js to
> end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove
> "type": "module" from /home/me/project/client/package.json.

Since I'm not in control of Next I don't know how to fix this (and shouldn't Next 12 be importing with ESM by default?)  Also my syntax in `babel.config.js` doesn't seem to even matter: whether I use ESM or Common JS, I get that same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You're importing Next.js itself as an ES Module which is not supported yet.

See: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/27876#discussioncomment-1163394